# calling Axis2 web service from ATL C++ client

Tags: c++, soap, atl, apache-axis

I have a simple POJO web service published with Axis2 on Tomcat5.5
I try to consume it with ATL C++ client and it fails.  Doing the same with a C# client works.
The problem is that ATL client sends soap body which looks like

```
<soap:Body>< xmlns="http://fa.test.com/xsd"></></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Notice the invalid  element in the middle.
I suspect it has something to do with UTF-8 because C# sends a header of

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

and ATL client doesn't.  Also when I look into some of the ATL SOAP internals I notice that a structure has two members: szName and szwName.  The first one is empty and produces the  element, the second one has a valid (?) name of testResponse (the method I'm calling is called "test").

Need advice as to where to go from here?

More details:
full message from ATL client:

```
POST /axis2/services/EnterpriseService.EnterpriseServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 304
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:test"
Accept: text/xml
Host: xxxxxxx
User-Agent: Microsoft-ATL-Native/8.00

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><soap:Body>< xmlns="http://fa.test.com/xsd"></></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Response from Axis2:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2008 15:31:57 GMT
Connection: close

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '>' (code 62); expected an element name.&#xd;
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,276]</faultstring><detail /></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Oh, and here is the good request coming from C# client:

```
POST /axis2/services/EnterpriseService.EnterpriseServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
Via: 1.1 ANGEL-ISLAND
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.1433)
Host: xxxxxxx:8080
SOAPAction: "urn:test"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 236

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body /></soap:Envelope>
```

In C# case the soap:body is blank.

Comment: Could you be more specific...what's the invalid element in the middle?  What header does C# send?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Posted more details above, the invalid element in the middle is "</>".

Answer (score 2):

ATL Server is entirely capable of generating the request correctly. Looks like there's some issue with the WSDL. My cursory test generates the request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <soap:Body></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

for an ASP.NET Web service with `SoapParameterStyle.Bare`. Do you have a `<wsdl:part>` element in the input message? Can you post the WSDL service description?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with UTF-8.

The valid message from C# doesn't have anything inside the soap:Body, while the invalid message has .  It looks like the ATL C++ client is trying to force something inside the SOAP body when there shouldn't be anything there at all.

Note also that the C# client doesn't include a testResponse element in its message.

I'd look the code some more where it uses szName and see if that's where it's generating the .  It shouldn't be doing that.